# How to recover from errors in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, error-handling

I am readying an Angular 5 application for production and I've noticed that even with 'production mode' enabled, Angular recovers very poorly from zoned errors. Specifically, after an error is thrown within the application, it seems that Angular fails to remove DOM nodes, instead just adding additional DOM nodes below it.

I know that I haven't added any code, because this is more of a conceptual question about how Angular works -- but it seems like in a production application, there must be a way to gracefully continue operation after hitting a javascript error.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This question is vague. I think you need to provide some code, and a demo to reproduce your issue in isolation. This may be something to do with your app. Try [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/) for a live demo.

Comment: I think, I sometimes catch myself thinking about same issue. The question, however, is not suited for SO in its current shape as @elclanrs. I recommend you provide a specific case to talk about: both the code which leads to an error; the observed undesired behavior; and the way you'd like the error to be handled.

Comment: @elclanrs Wow, thank you so much. Stackblitz.com looks amazing. I will try to create a live demo of it there and repost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm so sorry for the vague question. [This is the issue I was referring to.](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19093) It was resolved in September and merged in sometime since then. Updating @angular/platform-browser to 5.1.3 fixed the problem for me.